# Stay in the current directory after bash script

Tags: git, bash, path

I am trying to clone and install dependency in one line script. `git clone https://github.com/Study-Master/Java-WebSocket.git /tmp/socket && cd /tmp/socket && mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`, this is what I typed. But this command will leave current directory and go to `/tmp/socket` after execution. Is there any way that I can keep staying in current directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can keep staying in current directory.

Yes.  Execute your command in a subshell, i.e. by saying `( command )` (enclose the command within parenthesis):

```
( git clone https://github.com/Study-Master/Java-WebSocket.git /tmp/socket && cd /tmp/socket && mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just save the directory you need.

```
PWD=$(pwd)
```

... executes `pwd` and saves the output to `$PWD`.

So your command could look like this:

```
PWD=$(pwd); git clone https://github.com/Study-Master/Java-WebSocket.git /tmp/socket && cd /tmp/socket && mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true; cd $PWD
```

And you're back.

Comment: Better yet, use `pushd` and `popd`.

Comment: Right @BroSlow - forgot about `cd -` goes back to `$OLDPWD`.